# How to switch from the default kernel module netkey to klips for Libreswan (IPsec)?

Tags: ipsec, libreswan

Seek your guidance on setting up Libreswan with `klips` other than `netkey`. Let us start from the beginning.

I installed Libreswan v4.4 and it pops up with this: `Linux Libreswan 4.4 (netkey) on 5.4.0-1047-aws`. I begin to have issues with the AMI I built since our architecture uses `klips`, not `netkey`.

I read online Libreswan has removed `klips` from v4.0 onward: https://libreswan.org/wiki/FAQ. After reading this post from Libreswan, I installed Libreswan 3.30 and got this: `Linux Libreswan 3.30 (netkey) on 5.4.0-1047-aws`. It still shows `netkey`, so after some more digging into it. I would have to modify IPsec from the file itself: `/etc/ipsec.conf`. As I was going to modify the file inside I noticed there is no `protostack` to change the default to `klips`. I experimented by adding `protostack=klips` to the setup and after restarting `ipsec.service` it gave `Failed error`. Research more in the documentation and found `klips` has been removed:

> protostack

> decide which protocol stack is going to be used. Valid values are "xfrm" and "bsd". This option should no longer be set, as the stack is currently auto-detected. The values "klips, "mast", "netkey", "native", "kame" and "auto" are obsolete. The option is kept only because it is suspected that Linux and BSD will get userspace stacks with IPsec support soon (such as dpdk).

If anyone has experience in IPsec and Libreswan, I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!